# How do i build an application against HDP 2.6.1.0 stack

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to build a java application that runs a sqoop job, does some hdfs operations and alters metadata in hive.

To achie all this, I have created a maven project, but i run into dependency issues all the time.

Can somebody give me a example pom.xml, so I can start to write my application?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[HDP Maven Artifacts](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.2/bk_command-line-installation/content/download_hdp_maven_artifacts.html)

[pom.xml repositories](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/74655/where-can-i-find-hdp-maven-repos.html)

```
<repository>
 <releases>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
 </releases>
 <snapshots>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
 </snapshots>
 <id>hortonworks.extrepo</id>
 <name>Hortonworks HDP</name>
 <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>

<repository>
 <releases>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
 </releases>
 <snapshots>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
 </snapshots>
 <id>hortonworks.other</id>
 <name>Hortonworks Other Dependencies</name>
 <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public</url>
</repository>
```

Add `<dependency>` section for example, `hadoop-common:2.7.3.2.5.0-37` where that is the hadoop version + HDP version

Comment: which dependencies do i need for example for reading and writing files to hdfs? I have problems including hadoop-core. there is no version 2.7.3.2.5.0-37 in the repository. Which of the existing should i use?

Comment: You can use hadoop-common, but there is also hadoop-client and hadoop-hdfs. Also, since you're on a 2.6 cluster, you wouldn't use a 2.5 version anyway

Comment: You can browse that URL directly to find the versions http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/